# Configuring ssh virtualbox gitlab runner

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, virtualbox, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm setting up a new VirtulBox Machine Linux Ubuntu on my Windows 10 host for a simple gitlab CI runner.

Here my runner configuration (config.toml)

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "virtualbox"
  url = "****"
  token = "****"
  executor = "virtualbox"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "mauro"
    password = "mauro"
  [runners.virtualbox]
    base_name = "ubuntu.dev"
    user = "mauro"
    password = "mauro"
    identity_file = "/home/mauro/.ssh/id_rsa"
    disable_snapshots = false
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

When I use the runner I have the following output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.9.0 (692ae235)
  on virtualbox 8W5MbzNs
Using VirtualBox version 6.0.4r128413 executor...
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:53370->127.0.0.1:53168: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Inside the runners.virtualbox section you don't need the user, password, or identity_file.
The identity_file goes into the runners.ssh section.

I had similar issues when trying to just install the gitlab runner.
This gitlab runner worked for me - https://github.com/ayufan/gitlab-ci-multi-runner

Comment: Hi! Answers where the actual answer is on a linked page are likely to get deleted. The link could go dead, so you should put the key points from the link into the text of your answer so it'll still be useful even if the link goes dead.

Comment: The link is just a reference to where i found a working install - the real answer is about removing the identify_file, user and password section from runners.virtualbox

Comment: Ah, lemmie do a quick edit then to make that a bit clearer.